# escape special character using sed not working

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I know lot of questions have been written about it, but didn't work for me.
I am working in bash, and would like replace a string with escaped special characters:

```
echo "abm1c/def/sdfd/sync/sdff.jar/rtets.jar/fg/gdf/ggdg/dg/adg/TextParser$2.class," | sed -e "s#\([]*^+\.\$[-]\)##g"
```

Obviously output was incorrect.
Can you please provide me with the correct `sed` command.

Comment: correct command for what? What output did you want?

Comment: I don't like the escaping with normal sed. Extended Regex with using `-E` is much more familiar.

Comment: I want to escape the special characters in above string. Like forward slash, dollar sign, singe dot ,

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your expected output so we can be sure we are giving you what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong. It looks like you are trying to use `\( \)` to define a character class. You can't. Those are capture groups, they let you refer to what was matched inside them as `\1` (or `\2`, `\3` for subsequent groups). A character class is defined using `[]`. What you want to do is capture any match of the character class to replace it with itself escaped:

```
$ echo 'abm1c/def/sdfd/sync/sdff.jar/rtets.jar/fg/gdf/ggdg/dg/adg/TextParser$2.class,' |
    sed -e 's#\([]*^+.$[/]\)#\\\1#g'
```

Note that you aklso need the `]` to be the first character in the character class. Otherwise, it is assumed to be the closing bracket. And you don't need to escape `.` or `$` when they're within a character class.

Finally, you could do this sort of thing more simply by using perl's `quotemeta`:

```
$ echo 'abm1c/def/sdfd/sync/sdff.jar/rtets.jar/fg/gdf/ggdg/dg/adg/TextParser$2.class,' | 
    perl -lne 'print quotemeta()'
abm1c\/def\/sdfd\/sync\/sdff\.jar\/rtets\.jar\/fg\/gdf\/ggdg\/dg\/adg\/TextParser\$2\.class\,
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working, but can we use this for all escape characters i.e.: ;'"`#$&*?[]<>{}\ as well?

Comment: @SoumaliChatterjee what do you mean? Did you try it with those characters and it failed?

Comment: @SoumaliChatterjee `echo ";'\"\`#$&*?[]<>{}\ " | perl -ne 'print quotemeta'`

Comment: Ofcourse, with my test case, like String "abm1c/def/sdfd/sync/sdff.jar", or "abm1c/def/sdfd/" it didn't. I am trying to understand if there may be any special character, which I have missed to include? Thanks

Comment: @SoumaliChatterjee no character is "special" in general. It will always depend on where you want to use them. But yes, perl's `quotemeta` will escape everything that isn't a simple ASCII word character (so everything that doesn't match `[A-Za-z_0-9]`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and patience. the regex is working for me.